# Trying to use keywords as identifiers in ANTLR4; not working

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to get some sql keywords to be accepted as identifiers, when used as identifiers. The Antlr book p210 suggests this trick:

```
id : 'if' | 'call' | 'then' | ID ;
```

I've got something similar but it's not working and I assume it's a misunderstanding on my part.
`regular_ident` is the parse rule for an identifier thus:

```
regular_ident :  // (1)
        KEYWORD_AS_IDENT
        |
        REGULAR_IDENT
    ;
```

`REGULAR_IDENT` is the main lex rule for idents. It's roughly this (simplified here), and it works:

```
REGULAR_IDENT :
        [a-zA-Z]  ( [a-zA-Z0-9] * )
    ;
```

`KEYWORD_AS_IDENT` is the list of special words, here's an extract:

```
KEYWORD_AS_IDENT :  // (2)
[...snip...]
  | FILESTREAM
  | SPARSE
  | NO
  | ACTION
  | PERSISTED
  | FILETABLE_DIRECTORY
  | FILETABLE_COLLATE_FILENAME
  | FILETABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT_NAME
  | FILETABLE_STREAMID_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
  | FILETABLE_FULLPATH_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
  | COLUMN_SET
  | ALL_SPARSE_COLUMNS
 ;
```

where components are defined elsewhere:

```
SPARSE : 'sparse' ;
NO     : 'no'
(etc)
```

If I give it `fetch aaa` as input ('aaa' is not a keyword), it parses:

[image: successfully parsing a normal identifier]

but if I give it `fetch sparse` it fails - 'sparse' is a keyword:

[image: failing to parse with a keyword]

perhaps I'm being dumb but I can't see why, as `SPARSE` is a member of `KEYWORD_AS_IDENT`.
If I cut & paste some of (2) into (1) to get this:

```
regular_ident :
    FILESTREAM
  | SPARSE
  | NO
  | ACTION
  | PERSISTED
  | FILETABLE_DIRECTORY
        |
    REGULAR_IDENT
    ;
```

it suddenly is ok with `fetch sparse` as it now treats 'sparse' as an regular_ident:

[image]

but why does (1) not work?
I can fix it trivially by inlining all of `KEYWORD_AS_IDENT` but I need to know what I'm missing.

All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Reply from Eric Vergnaud from google group antlr-discussion:

> `LAST` is declared before `KEYWORD_AS_IDENT` so when the lexer
>   encounters 'last', it generates a `LAST` token, not a
>   `KEYWORD_AS_IDENT`. Your start rule does not accept `LAST` token as a
>   valid input, hence the shouting. Your grammar will actually NEVER
>   produce a `KEYWORD_AS_IDENT` token, because another valid token will
>   match before. It seems you are trying to get the lexer do the job of
>   the parser i.e. handle multiple semantic alternatives, but at the time
>   the token reaches the parser it's too late... Have you tried making
>   KEYWORD_AS_IDENT a parser rule (lowercase) rather than a lexer rule?

So my understanding of the lexer was faulty, and he's correct that I was trying to get it to do the parser's job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using your second approach in my own grammars (e.g. [MySQL.g](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/library/mysql.parser/grammar/MySQL.g#L3560)) as this was the only way to get this reliably working. This is however still ANTLR3 there. And I used kinda hack to change the token type recognized by the rule `keyword` so that it returns IDENTIFIER, instead of the individual keyword tokens.

Comment: "...only way to get this reliably working". Curious. Seems impossible it's a bug but I'll dig and try to reproduce minimally. As for keyword hackery, if the language is mucky, and TSQL is, the parsing only reflects that. Thanks